# O que pode acontecer com meu projeto se eu remover o ambiente virtual configurado para ele?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pip

Digamos que criei um ambiente virtual pelo virtualenvwrapper `$ mkvirtualenv venv`. Crio o meu projeto, faço as configurações necessárias, começo a trabalhar no projeto e um belo dia eu faço a remoção do ambiente virtual `$ rmvirtualenv venv`.

Quais são os efeitos que poderiam acontecer no meu projeto?

Comment: Se o seu projeto não estiver ativo não vai acontecer nada, mas é interessante você guardar em um arquivo todos os pacotes instalados nesse ambiente virtual, para isso use `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Comment: Eu poderia iniciar um novo ambiente virtual a partir do requirements.txt?

Comment: Após recriar o ambiente basta usar o comando `pip install requirements.txt` e todos os pacotes requeridos pelo projeto serão instalados.

Comment: Faltou o `-r`: `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Muito bom, cara! Valeu demais.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ideia de um ambiente virtual é justamente propiciar um ambiente para o seu projeto, por mais redundante que isso pareça. Isso é, enquanto você souber configurar um ambiente para o seu projeto, tanto faz se você excluir o ambiente no qual você está trabalhando. Aliás, você pode até recriar esse ambiente em uma outra máquina (por exemplo em um servidor remoto) que seu projeto funcionará.

No entanto, guardar na cabeça todas as configurações do seu projeto (e, possivelmente de vários outros) é algo um tanto quanto problemático. Você pode esquecer de alguma dependência específica e enfrentar bastante dificuldade para recriar o seu ambiente. Para tanto, é comum salvar junto com o seu projeto uma lista dos pacotes dos quais ele depende. Você pode criar essa lista utilizando o pip:

```
pip freeze > dependencias.txt
```

Se você der uma olhada no arquivo gerado, verá que, além dos nomes dos pacotes, também estão incluídas suas respectivas versões. Em função disso, é bastante aconselhável que você inclua esse arquivo no seu sistema de controle de versões.

Com isso, caso você exclua sem querer o seu ambiente virtual, ou precise rodar o seu projeto em uma outra máquina, basta você instalar os pacotes contidos nessa lista. Novamente, o pip tem um comando para isso. Após criar e ativar um novo ambiente virtual, rode:

```
pip install -r dependencias.txt
```

E pronto, seu projeto deverá funcionar propriamente.

Comment: Perfeito, meu caro! Obrigado.

Comment: Só lembrando que é melhor usar todos os nomes em ingles - no caso desse arquivo, há ate uma razão mais forte para o nme dele ser "requirements.txt": vários sistemas automaticos de recriação de ambiente, e muitos, ams muitos desenvoledores Python esperam que as dependencias estejam num arquivo com este nome: "requirements.txt"